# Open Quote expected for "ApplicationVersion" associated with an element type "ApplicationName"

Tags: java, linux, bash, shell, echo

```
echo "<Transaction><TypeofTrans>G5</TypeofTrans><Priority>7</Priority>
<ContentType>LIVE</ContentType><OrigAgency>generic</OrigAgency><DestAgency>generic</DestAgency>
<Sender><OperatorID>JOE</OperatorID><HostName>DESKTOP-5X</HostName><BPID>1</BPID>
<ApplicationName ApplicationVersion="SP1.1">TEW</ApplicationName></Sender>
<ID>$id</ID><Date>20210217</Date>" > "$xml_dir/$id.xml"    

    : > "$trigger_dir/$id.trigger"
```

I am trying to pinpoint why "SP1.11" is giving me this error.

Comment: You have to escape a double-quote that's meant to be included in a double-quoted string.

Comment: If you look at the contents of the file, you'll see something like `<ApplicationName ApplicationVersion=SP1.1>`; the quotes meant for the attribute value were instead treated as syntax by `bash`.

Comment: @chepner could you provide for me the proper syntax for a double quoted string within an echo statemenet?

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the nested double quotes so that they are treated as literal characters in the string, rather than prematurely closing and re-opening the quoted parts of the string.

```
echo "...<ApplicationName ApplicationVersion=\"SP1.1\">TEW</ApplicationName>..." > "$xml_dir/$id.xml"
```

There's also the option of simply switching quotes, as quotes don't define a string; they just provide bulk escaping for part of a string.

For example:

```
echo '<Transaction><TypeofTrans>G5</TypeofTrans><Priority>7</Priority><ContentType>LIVE</ContentType><OrigAgency>generic</OrigAgency><DestAgency>generic</DestAgency><Sender><OperatorID>JOE</OperatorID><HostName>DESKTOP-5X</HostName><BPID>1</BPID><ApplicationName ApplicationVersion="SP1.1">TEW</ApplicationName></Sender>'"<ID>$id</ID><Date>20210217</Date>" > "$xml_dir/$id.xml"
```

Much of the string is wrapped in single quotes, including the part that contains double quotes. Only the last section that requires parameter expansion uses double quotes.